# Unable to nest Types in GraphQL Schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I am having a very hard time trying to find out why my PageType on "page/pages" is giving "PageType is not defined", is there a different way I am suppose to reference it? I have a feeling this may be a simple overlook with how to reference other types

```
const PageType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Page',
  fields: {
    _id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID) },
    title: { type: GraphQLString },
    subtitle: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    page: {
      type: PageType
    }
    pages: {
      type: new GraphQLList(PageType),
    }
  },
});
```

Error (Mainly to help others search a similar problem):

```
ReferenceError: PageType is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\src\data\types\PageType.js:50:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\server.js:731:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\src\data\schema.js:1:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\server.js:1098:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\server.js:7455:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:19:1)
    at H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\webpack:\webpack\bootstrap 8ce5b4572987765a465d:65:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (H:\Coding\Projects\react-starter-kit\build\server.js:71:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty straight forward.. you're trying to reference PageType before that assignment is made. Same error would occur with a minimal example:

```
const foo = {
  innerFoo: foo // error: foo is not defined
}
```

This is why functions, often referred to as thunks are used in these recursive situations

```
const foo = {
  innerFoo: () => foo
}
```

By the time `foo.innerFoo()` is called, `foo` will already be defined and this will work. GraphQL schemas support creating fields as functions for this very reason.

```
const FooType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Foo',
  fields: () => ({ // fields is a "thunk"
    foo: {
      type: FooType
    },
    foos: {
      type: new GraphQLList(FooType),
    }
  }),
})
```

Comment: Seriously thank you so much, that worked perfectly.  The detailed answer greatly increases my understanding of the language